# Spring Batch Process Implementation on Existing Project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

Greeting guys! I'm working on the business based project developed on Spring MVC Framework with Angular JS. Now as part of my project there are some heavy processing that needs to be done which should run in background like File Processing, Validations, DB Store & retrieval, Business Rules processing etc.

I'm also newbie in these web based technologies so please help me out.

> To achieve this I started with the Spring Batch Process, read the
>   tutorial from below:
>
> docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html
>   (not allowed to post more than 2 links so pasting like this)
>
> Understood the Tutorial and found some examples like below:
>
> www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/spring-batch-tutorial.html
>   (not allowed to post more than 2 links so pasting like this)
>
> https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/
>
> (Since my existing Project is purely Java based (no XML based
>   configurations) so I searched accordingly and found above links
>   examples.)
>
> Now while going through those examples, whatever the examples I saw
>   are only given of standalone implementation i.e. no existing project
>   implementation I found as such, so what I did was extracted the pom.xml
>   configurations from these examples & integrated with the existing
>   pom.xml file.
>
> So after this when I added the desired springbatch directory in my existing project from these examples and tried to run it using mvn clean install it started failing like below:
>
> [Spring-boot-maven-plugin repackage goal error using nar-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353424/spring-boot-maven-plugin-repackage-goal-error-using-nar-maven-plugin)
>
> so I searched over the internet with the issue & found conclusion as
>   mentioned in the above link and added an additional classifier line in
>   my pom.xml changes, so after that it started working fine & then I was
>   able to generate the two war files.
>
> So when I deployed those wars under the WildFly it started failing
>   continuously with very huge errors.
>
> Below is my integrated POM File (the changes that I made in my original pom.xml file is present under double asterisks as below)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.business.alysisapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>analysisapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>Analysis App</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    **<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>**

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    **<start-class>com.Test</start-class>**
  </properties>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Web.xml is now configured programmatically in SpringWebAppInitializer.java name -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\developer\Documents\WildFly\standalone\deployments</outputDirectory>
                    <!-- WAR name -->
                    <warName>analysisapp</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            **<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>**
        </plugins>
        <finalName>analysisapp</finalName>
    </build>

  <dependencies>
    **<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>**
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Batch unit test -->
        **<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>**
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet API -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-flow</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-bpmn2</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-flow-builder</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For file upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Amazon S3 service (file upload) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Drool Rules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

> And this is the POM file of the example from the web that I used &
>   added these changes in my actual POM.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.danibuiza.javacodegeeks</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-Batch-Tutorial-Annotations</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.Test</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Batch unit test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> I searched a lot over stackoverflow and other possible options via google but is out of luck. Being new to this Spring Batch Process I'm really not sure how to
>   proceed from here as this is a blocker for me and I'm struggling for 5
>   straight days. It's a kind request please advise how do I proceed so
>   that I'll be able to integrate the Spring Batch Process with my
>   existing application. Also this might be a duplicate issue but it
>   would be great if someone can point me to the better direction so that
>   I can start from there.
>
> Logs after running the Wildfly:

```
2016-03-25 16:16:22,957 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYDS0010: Scan found incompletely copied file content for deployment C:\Users\developer\Documents\WildFly\standalone\deployments\analysisapp.war. Deployment changes will not be processed until all content is complete.
2016-03-25 16:16:35,617 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location C:\Users\developer\Documents\WildFly\standalone\data\content\53\45eaa8fbc1f098ffb898ba09eabe4a152de5fa\content
2016-03-25 16:16:35,678 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 131) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /analysisapp
2016-03-25 16:16:35,682 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 131) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcher'
2016-03-25 16:16:35,684 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 131) Closing Analysis App: startup date [Fri Mar 25 15:48:21 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-03-25 16:16:35,698 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 131) Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-03-25 16:16:35,698 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 131) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-03-25 16:16:36,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment analysisapp.war (runtime-name: analysisapp.war) in 448ms
2016-03-25 16:16:36,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "analysisapp.war" (runtime-name: "analysisapp.war")
2016-03-25 16:16:58,592 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2016-03-25 16:16:58,597 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2016-03-25 16:16:58,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver (version 2.3)
2016-03-25 16:16:58,718 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
2016-03-25 16:16:58,722 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
2016-03-25 16:16:58,722 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0013: Deployment deployment "analysisapp.war" contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was not found. (No beans.xml nor class with bean defining annotations)
2016-03-25 16:16:58,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = analysisapp.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
2016-03-25 16:16:58,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = analysisapp.war_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
2016-03-25 16:16:58,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = analysisapp.war_org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver_2_3
2016-03-25 16:16:58,806 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 279) Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@5538eb02, com.bizmerlin.config.SpringWebAppInitializer@5466ddd5]
2016-03-25 16:16:58,838 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 279) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.11-jbossorg-1 20150505-1501 for context '/analysisapp'
2016-03-25 16:17:13,858 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 279) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-03-25 16:17:13,858 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 279) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2016-03-25 16:17:13,916 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 279) Refreshing Analysis App: startup date [Fri Mar 25 16:17:13 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-03-25 16:17:13,938 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 279) Registering annotated classes: [class com.bizmerlin.config.ApplicationContextConfiguration]
2016-03-25 16:17:13,954 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 279) Scanning base packages: [com.bizmerlin]
2016-03-25 16:17:14,083 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 279) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: VFS resource ["/C:/Users/developer/Documents/WildFly/bin/content/analysisapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/bizmerlin/config/EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration.class"]; nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:226)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:219)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.registerDefaultValues(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.doVisitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.doVisitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:67)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:279)
    ... 19 more

2016-03-25 16:17:14,282 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 279) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./analysisapp: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./analysisapp: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: VFS resource ["/C:/Users/developer/Documents/WildFly/bin/content/analysisapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/bizmerlin/config/EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration.class"]; nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: VFS resource ["/C:/Users/developer/Documents/WildFly/bin/content/analysisapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/bizmerlin/config/EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration.class"]; nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:224)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: VFS resource
```

Comment: Please find below the logs which are getting generated and there are two war files analysisapp.war & analysisapp-exec.war and both are generated in .failed mode. Logs in the next comment

Comment: Use pastebin if not possible to post log here

Comment: I'm not to sure but I question that you can run the batch job inside a web container. Maybe you wan't to have a look at [Spring Batch configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html)

Comment: Please find the full logs at below link :
http://pastebin.com/dy5gxPt2

Comment: @Patrick :    I've seen that thing as I've read the original doc from there itself but the thing is, that doc is given in xml based format & i want to configure the changes in the JAVA based format using beans as you can see below example which I've taken the reference:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/spring-batch-tutorial.html

I'm looking for something like this. Please advise.

Comment: @BilboBaggins : Any more advices ?

Answer (score 0):

The initial error is :

```
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: 
Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
```

It looks like you are having a version problem. This may be caused by using spring classes of incompatible versions together.

Have a look at the versions you are using in both modules with mvn dependency:tree [mvn dependency:tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

If you find differences, resolve them changing `<version>` or using `<dependencyManagement>`

**EDIT :**
This warning appears, because you have the dependency to org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml twice in a 'dependencyManagement' and with the two different versions.

Go through you poms and look where this may happen. Remove one of it and it could work.

a dependency management

Comment: @Stefab Isele - Apologies for the delayed response but like you suggested I tried the command but I don't see any of the expected version conflict. Please have a look at the result of the output here : http://pastebin.com/GTtKC9EY